# Creating array of pointers using new such that they are not initialized to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

When I use this:

```
int** newData = new int*[100];
```

I get array of 100 objects (pointers) and default constructor is called on them, it causes pointers to be `NULL`.

If this is critical part of code and I want to avoid the nullification of the array, can I avoid it in a nice way? (without using `malloc`)

Comment: The default constructor isn't called. http://ideone.com/Uinud

Comment: you need to run each constructor in a loop

Comment: If they happen to be NULL, it is just by coincidence, or perhaps some debugging option in the compiler.

Comment: If at some point you *do* want the initialization to `NULL` guaranteed, use `new int*[100]();` (note the trailing parenthesis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quality of implementation issue. The pointers are not guaranteed to be initialized in the code that you have shown. There is no other way of dynamically allocating an an array of pointers in C++ that is guaranteed to be more performing.

(Pointers don't have constructors, they are either initialized or left uninitialized.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no `constructor` call made in your case, what you get is an array of 100 pointers that either happen to be filled with zeroes or the compiler has put a code to do so. The language standard doesn't require this array to be initialized when the `new` is called.

Now, to your other question: if this is in a `critical part of code` - why not simply **pre-allocate** the needed array at program's initialization time? This way you won't need to worry about some random code setting your pointers to a pre-defined value.